# Showing a hide mobile-responsive div

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a row with 3 columns.

```
|   1   |   2   |    3    |
```

I want to show all columns in Large and Medium screen. But in Mobile screen I want to show just first column. This work I have done by this code.

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                <asp:Label ID="lblCatagory1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 hidden-sm hidden-xs" id="cat2">
                <asp:Label ID="lblCatagory2" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 hidden-sm hidden-xs" id="cat3">
                <asp:Label ID="lblCatagory3" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
        </div>
</div>
```

Now I want to create a button in mobile version below this code. By clicking this button others two column will show. How is this possible in `Bootstrap/JavaScript` **Creating button is not my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this.

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
  $('#cat2, #cat#3').toggleClass('hidden-sm').toggleClass('hidden-xs')
})
```

Comment: may be a typo .. its should be #cat3 instead on #cat#

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.. 
add an id to column 1 and then using jquery() you can add class to col 2 and col3 and display them in same row..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#button1').click(function () {
        $('#cat2, #cat3').toggleClass('hidden-sm').toggleClass('hidden-xs');
        $('#cat1, #cat2, #cat3').addClass('col-sm-4 col-xs-4').addClass('col-sm-4 col-xs-4').addClass('col-sm-4 col-xs-4');
    });
```

Hope this helps